# Guessing the kernel of an integral

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

Suppose I have a function $h(x_1,x_2)$ which is a polynomial function of degree $2n$ with all even powers;
$$h(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{i,j=0}^{n} c_{ij} x_1^i x_2^j$$
where $c_{ij}, x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is there a simple integral transform that I can apply on $h(x_1,x_2)$ such that I can extract the terms with the largest degree, i.e. is there a simple $F(y_1,y_2; x_1,x_2)$ such that
$$ g(y_1,y_2) = c_{nn} y_1^n y_2^n + c_{2n,0} y_1^{2n} +c_{0,2n} y_2^{2n} +\dots = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx F(y_1,y_2; x_1,x_2) h(x_1,x_2)?$$
where $\dots$ denote all terms of degree $2n$.

As a simple example, let's set $x_2 =1, x_1=x$ and consider $h(x) = 3x^4 + 7x^2 +2$, does a simple $F(x,y)$ exist such that $g(y) = 3y^4$?

Thanks for any help, my intuition about integral transforms is really bad, I tried some simple test functions for $F(y,x)$ but it didn't work out.

Comment: @Gonçalo Physics wise, the way the problem is set up involves evaluating a complicated integral transform. So I was trying the reverse way, assuming I know the answer in a certain limiting case, is it possible to guess the simplified transform, and then seeing if the complicated transform reduces to this simplified one in the same limit.
By the way, what differential operator will extract these terms, say if $n$ is arbitrary, sorry for being naive?